# Is there a way to recover uncommitted git working tree?

Tags: git

I've got a nightmare today, all my 3-hour long works has gone, here's how :

1. You have unsaved works in your working tree, `git status` told that
2. Switch branch using --merge , but you've made a mistake which the branch you're checking out is not the one you're about to, and merge conflict happens...
3. You don't wanna solve that or just don't wanna do useless stuffs, so you do : `git merge --abort` and...
4. BANG, where's my last work? It's all gone, and you realized that you've just has a nightmare.

So that's my story, may be I'll use some dark art to recall my lost souls from the abyss, or maybe I'll just remember to not repeat that till my last day on earth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to recover what has never been committed or stashed at some point in time. You should never merge uncommitted changes. [git-merge(1)](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) has this to say:

> [...] if there were uncommitted changes when the merge started (and especially if those changes were further modified after the merge was started), git merge --abort will in some cases be unable to reconstruct the original (pre-merge) changes. Therefore:
>
> **Warning**: Running git merge with non-trivial uncommitted changes is discouraged: while possible, it may leave you in a state that is hard to back out of in the case of a conflict.

Comment: So a valuable experience for me that to pay more attention to Warnings and frequently destructive-easy commands

Comment: You'll probably disagree but 3 hours is not too bad. If you commit regularly, it is very hard to really lose something. Btw the idiom for your use case would be `git stash;git checkout other_branch;git stash pop`. In case of conflicts, the stash is not removed so you don't run the risk of easily losing stuff.